# Using hex string as Map key best performance way

Tags: javascript, mongodb, performance, hex

I am getting MongoDB `ObjectId`s, which are 12 bytes and their hex string looks like this: `62d34be4f8cd489f6d5b8e0e`.

I want to use the object id as a map key like this:

```js
new Map().set(ObjectId('62d34be4f8cd489f6d5b8e0e'),"value")
```

That doesn't really work because each `ObjectId` object is unique so two with the same id are not equal objects.

There are a few ways I can think of:

- Use the hex string as map key:

```js
new Map().set("62d34be4f8cd489f6d5b8e0e", "value")
```

- Use a buffer / Uint8Array, and use some special Map which works with arrays as keys

```js
new Map().set(Buffer.from("62d34be4f8cd489f6d5b8e0e", "hex"), "value")
```

- Turn the buffer into a 12 byte string which looks like `b�K���H�m[�\x0E`

```js
new Map().set(Buffer.from("62d34be4f8cd489f6d5b8e0e", "hex").toString(), "value")
```

- Turn the buffer into a number (this turns a 12 byte buffer into a 16 byte number so it seems a little wierd)

```js
new Map().set(Buffer.from("62d34be4f8cd489f6d5b8e0e", 'hex').readInt16BE(), "value")
```

Which method has the best performance?

Comment: You want someone to eyeball your code and tell you which is best performance?  Why not test it yourself - https://jsbench.me/ for example.

Comment: I'll eyeball it! Buffer.from() will iterate the string, toString() and .readInt() will iterate again. Just setting the string doesn't iterate the string and seems the obvious choice.  (I can even foretell the future: a future commenter will say something about premature optimization)

Comment: @danh Actually I think ObjectId internally stores it as a `Buffer`, so it will have to convert `Buffer` to hex string. Is doing that still the obvious choice?

Comment: @programmerRaj, don't all of the options presume you've extracted a string?